# Hay alguna forma de acceder a la opcion que selecciona el usuario de Sweet Alert2? En este ejemplo a Oranges y no a fruta4?

Tags: javascript

Aqui empeiza el codigo
necesito acceder a por ejemplo Oranges y mandarlos a php para obtener las respuestas y mandarlos a una base de datos. Gracias por la ayuda

```
const { value: fruit } = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select field validation',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    fruta1: 'Apples',
    fruta2: 'Bananas',
    fruta3: 'Grapes',
    fruta4: 'Oranges'
  },
  inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (value === 'oranges') {
        resolve()
      } else {
        resolve('You need to select oranges :)')
      }
    })
  }
})

if (fruit) {
  Swal.fire(`You selected: ${fruit}`)
```

termina el codigo

Comment: donde quieres acceder al valor seleccionado?

Comment: Quiero jalarlo para mandarlo a php, queria ponerlo en un array para luego mandarlo a php

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente crear la variable que contiene las opciones fuera de del objeto de configuración de `Swal.fire` para tener acceso luego en el código a las opciones.

Y según el valor que seleccione el usuario tu tienes la `key`(lo devuelve sweetalert) y tienes el objeto con las opciones pues puedes acceder al valor.

Así.

```
const inputOptions = {
    fruta1: 'Apples',
    fruta2: 'Bananas',
    fruta3: 'Grapes',
    fruta4: 'Oranges'
};

const { value: fruit } = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select field validation',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: inputOptions,
  inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (value === 'oranges') {
        resolve()
      } else {
        resolve('You need to select oranges :)')
      }
    })
  }
})


if (fruit) {
  const valor = inputOptions[fruit];
  Swal.fire(`You selected: ${valor}`)
}
```